# UIViewController frame changes every time I ran the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code:

```
   PNRProfileViewController *vc = [[PNRProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PNRProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.delegate = self;
    self.profileVC_ = vc;

    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.profileVC_];
    AHLog(@"FRAME IS %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.profileVC_.view.frame));
    controller.view.frame = self.profileVC_.view.frame;
    controller.view.autoresizingMask = self.profileVC_.view.autoresizingMask;

    self.currentViewController_ = controller;
```

when I run this code, the frame height I got changes every time.. it's alternating between 416 and 460. I have no idea why this is. Any clue?

Comment: 44px is the size of most toolbars including navigation bars I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

44 pixels is the height of the navigation bar.

To keep the navigation bar and have your nib respect its size, go into your .xib file, select the view, then on the attributes tab, set the tab bar drop down to navigation bar.

To remove the navigation bar, after you alloc your NavigationController call `controller.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: The unfortunate problem is that if you push or pop from a view controller with a navigation bar visible to one where it is hidden, The height of the view's frame stays at 416 for a few seconds.

Comment: Ive noticed that too, and i havent yet come up with a solution